# Marathon says Docker in waiting state, docker engine says container is running

Tags: docker, mesos, marathon

I have a Marathon-Mesos-Docker in an inconsistent state where Marathon says the task is in a Waiting state, Mesos keeps trying to restart the task, but the container is actually running in Docker.

Anyone else seen this and, if so, what you did to fix it?

--John

Comment: Is there a failing health check?

Comment: @js84 Good question! No, because Marathon never gets to the running state from which a health check would be run.

Answer (score 1):

Okay, I was able to figure it out. The Mesos agent crashed and, therefore, it could not send zookeeper state changes to Marathon. Once I restarted the mesos agent, the state of the Marathon task switched to running